# Grep a word in files with specific file extension in windows

Tags: windows, search, grep

I would use the following command to grep a text in a directory with many files.

```
grep -irl "SampleText" *.txt
```

My case is to grep only in `.txt` files. While executing the above command in command prompt of windows it throws an error like

```
grep: *.txt: Invalid argument
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
grep --include=*.txt -irl . -e "SampleText"
```

remove the `l` argument to print the text and it's surrounding text too
and add the `n` argument to see the line number of the text you found

Use `man grep` for further info

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in utility?

```
findstr /s /i /m "SampleText" *.txt
```